# IOS - Linkedin integration for oauth2.0 with google oauth library -- Got 404 error(page not found)

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using google OAuth2.0 for LinkedIn integration in IOS. But I got 404 error when app try to get the accesstoken. Can you have a look at it and give me some guidance? Thanks in advance

I have tracked the request and have them below:

1. Generate the authorization code, the http request like below:
   https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=dqabmvt35aee&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2FOAuthCallback&response_type=code&scope=r_emailaddress&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef424
2. Then get the redirect URI like:
   http://www.google.com/OAuthCallback?code=AQRnqUBueoz5jZqolVl5suiUQFnLExkmRQSOdndgFK59t4cKC4EjUm38zTbXjDvLwWItUrYrXnOt6KRxTz_SZ5m0Qq3t9rZHG1q-aqltb79m7ZJ5K2Y&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef424
3. Do the post request for getting accessToken
   https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken/
   Request body like:
   client_id=dqabmvt35aee
   &client_secret=tlsAaUCZ5XtrTfHz
   &code=AQRnqUBueoz5jZqolVl5suiUQFnLExkmRQSOdndgFK59t4cKC4EjUm38zTbXjDvLwWItUrYrXnOt6KRxTz_SZ5m0Qq3t9rZHG1qaqltb79m7ZJ5K2Y
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2FOAuthCallback

And the got 404 error here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out by myself. What caused this issue is about the access token URL. I have the SLASH end of this URL which caused this issue. In google oauth 2.0 library, we should set the accesstoken url like "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken", not should be "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken/"

Comment: OH MY LORD!!!!! I can't possibly thank you enough!!! You have just saved me from the hours of suffering I was having with Google OAuth 2.0. I had the same issue :)